# Failed to load XML from SSIS package file

Tags: xml, vb.net, sql-server-2005, ssis

I've had to backwards convert my SSIS 2008 package to 2005 including converting all the C# script tasks to VB. After finishing this and getting it to run fine from Visual Studio, I went to deploy it to the server but when I import the package through SSIS into the 'File System' I get the following error:

```
Failed to load XML from package file "C:\filePath\packageName.dtsx" due to error 
0xC00CE513 "Whitespace is not allowed at this location. Line 7595, Column 82".  
This happens when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or 
loaded correctly into an XML document. This can be the result of either providing 
an incorrect file name to the LoadPackage method or the XML file specified having 
an incorrect format. ({EBEB7947-B9DA-4715-B7F7-D1E9CC8DAD6E})
```

Now when I open the package file up and go to that line this is what I have:

```
Dim logFilePath As String = Dts.Variables("LogFolder").Value.ToString() & "\LOG.txt"
```

Ive tried googling for the past hour and haven't been able to find anything, would really appreciate some help.

Comment: This has been resolved now. The issue was with copying the package through an RDP session via the clipboard, which for some reason was causing the file to become corrupt.

I fixed this by mapping a drive and copying it through that way instead, the original XML from the compiled package was well formed.

Comment: Ok I've just done that now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved now. The issue was with copying the package through an RDP session via the clipboard, which for some reason was causing the file to become corrupt. I fixed this by mapping a drive and copying it through that way instead, the original XML from the compiled package was well formed